# Why an ideal in a ring is a submodule of a free module over that ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

I know an ideal in a ring is a module over this ring, but I don't know why it's a submodule of a free module, what's the free module? Thank you.

Comment: Ideals are submodules of the ring considered as a module over itself (which is free by definition).

Comment: @Hanno that's what i thought: a commutative unital ring $R$ is a free $R$-module of rank of 1 right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fintely generated free $R$-module is isomorphic to $R^n$. Take $n=1$ and you see that $R$ is a free $R$-module. Now it is left to check that an ideal $I\subset R$ defines an $R$-submodule. But this is clear by definition. Is every step and the result clear to you?

Comment: Actually is $I$ additionally an embedded $R$-submodule of $R^n$ via the embedding of $R$ into $R^n$ ? (assuming that indeed $R$ is an $R$-submodule of $R^n$...i forgot this already)